# “IF” formula in excel using multiple conditions

Tags: excel

If A1 is less then 50 then A2 should be the same number. If it is between 50 and 100 then should round up to nearest 5. If above 100 it should round up to nearest 50. I can only get it in 2 formulas not 1.

```
=IF(C7>100,CEILING(C7,50),CEILING(C7,1))
```

­

```
=IF(AND(C7<100,C7>50),CEILING(C7,5),CEILING(C7,1))
```

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of your question, but I'm failing. How about you edit the question and put in some punctuation, so that people who read it can determine where a statement ends, where you are taking a breath, where the next statement starts? Since we can't hear you read this out loud, we really need punctuation to help us understand your wall of text.

Comment: And BTW when you compare one thing to the other it's less "than", with an `a`. If things are happening in sequence, it's one, "then" two, "then" three. These things matter when you present your problem in writing. It's very impolite to just write as it comes into your head and leave it to the reader to figure out what you actually mean.

Comment: i guess someone work it out cos got the answer

Comment: please mark the answer as described in the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try :

```
=IF(C7>100,CEILING(C7,50),IF(AND(C7<100,C7>50),CEILING(C7,5),CEILING(C7,1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the following formula in A2:

```
  =IF(A1<50,A1,IF(A1<100,CEILING(A1,5),CEILING(A1,50)))
```